# brew can't install numpy

Tags: numpy, homebrew

im trying to link numpy but it gives this error

```
youness-MacBook-Air:~ youneshussain$ brew link numpy
Linking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/numpy/1.26.4... 
Error: Could not symlink lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py
Target /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite numpy

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite numpy --dry-run
```

I tried to run this command `brew link --overwrite numpy` but it gives this error

```
youness-MacBook-Air:~ youneshussain$   brew link --overwrite numpy
Linking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/numpy/1.26.4... 
Error: Could not symlink lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy is not writable.
```

also this command `brew link --overwrite numpy --dry-run` and it give this error

```
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/f2py/tests/src/regression/gh25337
```

i googled the later message but couldn't find any

Comment: Do you need to use `sudo`? I don't use Mac myself so IDK, just an idea.

Comment: Can you attach the output of `brew doctor`?